# Can a deterministic language be accepted by a deterministic Push Down Automaton?

Tags: formal-languages, pushdown-automata, nondeterminism

I have a question that asks me to show that the PDA of the language L is not deterministic, but that the language is nevertheless deterministic. I was under the assumption that any deterministic language contains a PDA that is deterministic.

The language in question is: $L = \{w \in \{a,b\}^* : n_a(w) = n_b(w)\}$

Comment: Is $n_a(w)$ the amount of a's in $w$?

Comment: "the PDA of the language L is not X" -- there are many. Is one given? "language contains an automaton" -- that's misleading terminology. Languages like the one you give contain words. Automata accept languages. Also, regarding your tag choice: the given language is *not* regular.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, a deterministic language can trivially be accepted by a nondeterministic PDA. Simplest way to see it is that a deterministic PDA is just a special case of the non-deterministic one. If that isn't enough, for some transition

$\begin{align}
   \delta(q, a, A) = \{(p, \alpha)\}
\end{align}$

you can add the following, *without changing the language accepted*
(the modified PDA isn't deterministic, it is enabled to do completely pointless $\epsilon$ moves):

$\begin{align}
   \delta(q, \epsilon, A) = \{(q, A)\}
\end{align}$

Answer (score 0):

The definition of a deterministic context-free language is that it is a language that is accepted by a deterministic pushdown automaton.  Therefore, every deterministic context-free language can be recognized by a PDA that is deterministic.  In other words, the answer to your question is "no" (assuming I am understand correctly what you mean by "contain").  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_context-free_language.

Comment: Hm. I understand the question to mean, "can deterministic language be accepted by non-deterministic automata"? We'll have to wait for clarification.